# camel activemq component hang with instance on ec2 when transaction is enabled

Tags: transactions, amazon-ec2, jms, activemq-classic

I have an activemq running on ec2. When I ran my test without the JMS transaction enabled, the test works fine. However, once I enable the transaction, no message is delivered and the test just hang. (If I ran the same setting on my local activemq, it went fine.) I am wondering if there's something special I have to set when I use activemq with transaction enabled. Had anyone tried this combination?

Thanks,
JJ

P.S. snippet of my camel configuration is as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbcDriver}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbcUserName}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbcPassword}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbcUrl}"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbcMaxPoolSize}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
      class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${activeMQBrokerURL}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory"
      class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig"
      class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5"/>

    <!--
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
    -->
</bean>
```

Comment: include your test/client code...